# Same UISearchBar for entire app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I've seen a lot of apps that have a universal search bar that always remains at the top of the app. I have implemented a `UISearchBar` with a `UITableView` in one view controller.  I want to have the same search bar on other view controllers in my app.  How do I link these other `UISearchBars` to the one I have already created?  I.e., how do I configure these other `UISearchBars` so that they return the same search results and link to the same `UITableView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested view controllers may be what you need.

Define a “top view controller” that manages a “top view” containing a search bar and add your (table) views to the top view (using `-addSubview:` on the top view) and the associated view controller(s) to the top view controller (using `-addChildViewController:` in the top VC and on itself).

In Interface Builder, you can define a top view and inside it a “container view.” The system then handles the insertion of the subview and sub-view controller.

By defining a good view controller hierarchy, you make your app design more logical and clean. I’d recommend to take some time into investigating a good hierarchy before diving into coding.

A final note: the `UISearchDisplayController` is an object (apparently not a view controller) that superimposes a search bar above a view controller’s view. You might be able to simply apply it immediately above the top-most view controller (the one that is always visible, like a navigation controller). It’s worth looking into it, if you didn’t already. ;-)

---

### An example

#### View controller hierarchy

- `XYZTopViewController` (managing a `XYZTopView`)

  - `UINavigationController` (managing a private navigation view hierarchy defined by Apple)

    - `XYZFirstPageViewController` (managing a `XYZFirstPageView`) (the “root” view controller)
    - `XYZSecondPageViewController` (managing a `XYZSecondPageView`) (pushed by nav. controller when you need it to)

#### View hierarchy

- `XYZTopView`

  - `UISearchBar`

    - (private navigation view hierarchy defined by Apple)
    - `XYZFirstPageView`

      - (your view hierarchy belonging to the first page/screen)

Answer (score 2):

> Since you only every have one window per app, and view's don't have
>   levels, you have to make sure that view stays on top of the hierarchy,
>   no matter what. One relatively easy way is to add it directly to the
>   window above the rest of the interface (the navigation controller):

- [How to show a uiview alway on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843316/how-to-show-a-uiview-alway-on-top)

In applicationDidLaunch:

```
// After the main navigation controller or tab controller has been added
// either programmatically or in the xib:
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70,320,44)];
[self.window addSubview:searchBar];
```